# number of directed acyclic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given number of vertices $k$, how many DAGs over $k$ are there? I know from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Enumeration) that it can be computed in a recursive manner. I am wondering whether there are other simple formulas.

Comment: [This](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/18.pdf) is such beautiful theorem that is worth looking at.

Comment: @Luis this is similar to the Wiki one and it seems the only known formula to compute it. My next question is this number always greater than $2^k$?

Comment: To be completely honest, I do not know that much about graph theory. This is just a result I remember from my combinatorics class.

Comment: Is $a\to b$ different from $b\to a$? If so, then there are at least $k!$ of them, just counting the different orderings of $k$ objects, and that's much bigger than $2^k$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes.. I have tested it for several $k$'s and it's always larger than $2^k$. would you please refer me to a source for the relation between $k!$ and $2^k$..thanks

Comment: The source is half-a-minute's thought. $2^k$ is a product of $k$ numbers, each of which is a 2. $k!$ is also the product of $k$ numbers, almost all of which are bigger than 2. Can you take it from there?