# How many distinct simple cycles through a complete graph of size n are there?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given *n* vertices on a complete graph, I want to know how many distinct cycles can be formed that:

1. Start at one vertex and end at the same vertex
2. Never revisit a vertex besides the starting / ending vertex
3. Two cycles that visit the same vertices with different starting / ending vertices are considered to be the same cycke.

   - ex: A-B-C-A == B-C-A-B
4. Two cycles that visit the same verticies but in opposite orders are consider the same

   - A-B-C-A == A-C-B-A
5. We only count cycles that visit three or more distinct verticies

A small example using vertices A, B, C, and D. The possible cycles are:
A-B-C-A
A-D-C-A
A-B-D-A
B-C-D-B
A-B-C-D-A
A-B-D-C-A
A-D-B-C-A

**Is there a closed form formula for calculating how many cycles there are given just how many verticies there are in the graph,*n*?**

I've gotten some leads [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522737/how-many-distinct-acyclic-paths-through-a-complete-graph-of-size-n-are-there) but haven't been able to find an answer yet. I'm struggling with how to account for all the cycles that we consider to be identical.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Some questions: is the graph complete? what is an acyclic ring? are you talking about Hamilton cycle? please use MathJax

Comment: Hello! Yes, the graph is complete.   


By acyclic ring, I mean a path of verticies connected in a cycle. Forgive the inconsistent terminology, I'm quite new to graph theory.   
To my knowledge, this isn't quite the same as a Hamilton cycle. A Hamilton cycle visits every vertex in the graph exactly once, whereas the 'ring' I've describe could visit every vertex, but it could also visit only a subset of all vertices. I'm trying to find out how many rings could be formed in a complete graph with *n* verticies

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "up to circular order"?

Comment: The cycles $C_1 =(1,2,3,1),C_2=(1,3,2,1)$ are counted once.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker in your previous comment, I think you forgot a factorial.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yep, thanks for that. New Answer: I think you are asking how many hamiltonian cycles does $K_n$ (the complete graph with $n$ vertices) has, up to circular order.

The answer is $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting according to cycle length $k$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(k-1)!}{2}$$ cycles in the complete graph $K_n$, and this is [OEIS A002807](https://oeis.org/A002807).

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any intuition for the $\frac{(k−1)!}{2}$ term?

Comment: There are $k!$ permutations of the $k$ nodes chosen to be in the cycle.  Now divide by $k$ to account for the starting node, and divide by 2 to account for the direction.